# python csv dictionary format adjust

Tags: python, csv, date, datetime, dictionary

```
import os
from datetime import datetime, date
def convert_file(file_path):
    with open(file_path) as file:
        next(file) 
        weather={}
        for line in file:
            line = line.rstrip("\n") 
            x=line.split(",")
            a=x[3]
            b=[x[-2],x[-1],x[4]]
            weather[a]=b
        print(weather)
        file.close()

file_path=os.getcwd()+"/weatherdata.csv"
convert_file(file_path)
```

---

```
{'"2010-07-03"': ['"68"', '"52"', '"0.00"'], '"1969-08-23"': ['"81"', '"54"', '"0.00"'], '"1983-07-10"': ['"69"', '"54"', '"0.00"'], '"1983-09-17"': ['"61"', '"49"', '"0.00"'], '"1964-04-22"': ['"50"', '"35"', '"0.33"']
```

How do I make my output look like the sample output below?:
    Output dictionary (weather):

```
{datetime.date(2017, 12, 10): [49, 34, 0.0],
 datetime.date(2017, 12, 11): [49, 29, 0.0],
 datetime.date(2017, 12, 12): [46, 32, 0.0],
```

Comment: what is your logic? and how did you try to do it?

Comment: I tried datetime, int(), float(), but none of them worked, I guess its sth to do with the double qoutes.

Comment: I tried:            b=[int(x[-2]),int(x[-1]),float(x[4])]

Answer (score 0):

Consider parsing the CSV file using the `csv` library -- real world CSVs can be surprisingly complicated.
https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html

If you're going down the manual path, consider running each line through
`line.strip('"')` to remove the trailing/leading quotes and splitting with `line.split('","')` or similar to not include the quotes in the centre, assuming your CSV is nicely formatted (if not, **use the library**).

You can convert strings to numbers with `int(x)` and `float(x)`: something like 
`b2 = [int(b[0]), int(b[1]), float(b[2])` ought to help.

You can convert date-text to datetime objects with `datetime.strptime(date_string, format)` -- see https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior for more documentation, but you'll need `%Y-%m-%d` as your format string, I think.

Answer (score 0):

Better to use CSV module to handle csv file.
But this should help...

```
import os
import ast
from datetime import datetime


def convert_file(file_path):
    with open(file_path) as file:
        next(file) 
        weather={}
        for line in file:
            line = line.rstrip("\n") 
            x=line.split(",")
            a=x[3]
            b=[x[-2],x[-1],x[4]]
            weather[datetime.strptime(a, '"%Y-%m-%d"')]= [ast.literal_eval(i.replace('"', "")) for i in b]
        print(weather)
        file.close()

file_path=os.getcwd()+"/weatherdata.csv"
convert_file(file_path)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list comprehension with `datetime.strptime`, `int` and `float`. You can remove the double quotes in your strings via string slicing.

```
from datetime import datetime

d = {'"2010-07-03"': ['"68"', '"52"', '"0.00"'],
     '"1969-08-23"': ['"81"', '"54"', '"0.00"'],
     '"1983-07-10"': ['"69"', '"54"', '"0.00"'],
     '"1983-09-17"': ['"61"', '"49"', '"0.00"'],
     '"1964-04-22"': ['"50"', '"35"', '"0.33"']}

res = {datetime.strptime(k[1:-1], '%Y-%m-%d'): \
       [int(v[0][1:-1]), int(v[1][1:-1]), float(v[2][1:-1])] \
       for k, v in d.items()}
```

**Result**

```
print(res)

{datetime.datetime(1964, 4, 22, 0, 0): [50, 35, 0.33],
 datetime.datetime(1969, 8, 23, 0, 0): [81, 54, 0.0],
 datetime.datetime(1983, 7, 10, 0, 0): [69, 54, 0.0],
 datetime.datetime(1983, 9, 17, 0, 0): [61, 49, 0.0],
 datetime.datetime(2010, 7, 3, 0, 0): [68, 52, 0.0]}
```